# Perl, Selenium, and Unicode

Tags: perl, selenium

I'm using Perl's WWW::Selenium module for automated testing, and I get

> Timed out after 30000ms

on a particular element.

The element I'm looking for has the text 'Sort by name' followed by a thin down arrow -- it is not a down arrow from the keyboard. As an aid in troubleshooting, I used Selenium's

```
$return -> $sel->get_html_source();
```

function to get the HTML code and this is the output:

```
<a href="#">Sort by age �~F~S</a>
```

As an aid in troubleshooting, I decided to use the Data::Dumper with 'use utf8' at the top of the Perl script, and the output is a little different:

```
<li data-value=\"created_on-desc\" class=\"\">
    <a href=\"#\">Sort by age \x{2193}</a>
</li>
```

I have used the following Perl code in my script.

```
$locator = q{//a[contains(@href,"Sort by age �~F~S")]};
$ret = $sel->wait_for_element_present($locator, $timeout);
$ret = $sel->click($locator);
```

and

```
$locator = q{//a[contains(@href,"Sort by age \x{2193}")]};
$ret = $sel->wait_for_element_present($locator, $timeout);
$ret = $sel->click($locator);
```

and they both fail at

> Error requesting http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/: 
>   Timed out after 30000ms

Comment: What happens with `q{//a[contains(@href,"Sort by age")]};`? Or do other elements on the page match that as well?

Comment: Can you paste the source code here or that particular text here so that I can try it?